# Use textbox value in another cs file

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to add a WinForm into my Console App:

```
namespace ExchangeNativeDemo.Window
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to pass textbox1 value to Program.cs, like:

```
var emailaddress = textbox1.value
```

In program.cs:

```
using ExchangeNativeDemo.Window;

namespace ExchangeNativeDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
```

But I got the error:

> is inaccessible due to its protection level

What I missed?

Comment: Can I ask a simple question, Why not simply change the application to a WinApp instead?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a TextBox (or other control) to a WinForm using Visual Studio, the control is defaulted to [protected scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx), meaning that the only code that can access it is the code in the WinForm itself or classes that derive from it.

There are two common options:

1. Just change the TextBox from `protected` to `public`.  This breaks encapsulation a bit so this isn't my favorite.
2. Write a custom property that exposes the textbox's `Text` property, e.g.

   ```
   class Form1
   {
       //.....Other stuff....
       public string Text1Value
       {
           get { return this.textbox1.Text; }
       }
   }
   ```

   Since you know that it is supposed to be the email address, and you want to at least try to be a little encapsulated, you might actually want to name it `EmailAddressEntered` or something similar.

   ```
   public string EmailAddressEntered
   {
       get { return this.textbox1.Text; }
   }
   ```

   Then in your main program, create an instance of the form, display it, then read the property.

   ```
   void Main()
   {
       //....do other stuff....
       var form = new Form1();
       form.ShowDialog();
       var emailaddress = form.EmailAddressEntered;
   }
   ```

Also note, a TextBox does not have a Value.  The contents are stored in the Text property instead.

Also also note, your `main` function should contain a call to [Application.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx) or you'll find that `Form1` doesn't work very well.

Comment: You still can have syntax highlighting inside a list but have to use double indentation

Comment: Thanks. About Application.Run, after adding Application.Run();, my console application is not moving forward:

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var form = new Form1(); // Getting email address from form1.
            form.Show();

Answer (score 0):

- You need to make `textbox1` **public**,
- or add property to `Form1 that will expose its value:

  ```
  public string Textbox1Text
  {
      get { return textbox1.Text; }
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to declare your var as public otherwise it is automatically private. Try and let me know.